# unable to identify iframes using page-object

Tags: ruby, iframe, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I tried different ways to identify the nested frame using page-object i tried like
`in_iframe(index: 1) do |frame|..end` and i tried with id & class as well but no luck

```
<div id="tabsWrapper">
<table id="defaultTabs" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tabContentCell">
                <div id="tabContentContainer" style="height: 443px;">
                    <a id="top" name="top"></a>
                    <div id="tabDefaultContent"> </div>
                    <div id="tab14036918566282Content" class="tabContent" style="display: none;">
                        <iframe id="tab14036918566282Frame" class="portal xicSeamlessUI" width="100%" height="716px" frameborder="0" "="" name="tab14036918566282Frame" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="/mywork/ptl/secure/defaultportal" style="height: 443px;">
                            <!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html class="ltr yui3-js-enabled gecko ltr js firefox firefox24 firefox24-0 win secure" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab14036918654673Content" class="tabContent">
                        <iframe id="tab14036918654673Frame" class="portal xicSeamlessUI" width="100%" height="716px" frameborder="0" "="" name="tab14036918654673Frame" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="/ncs/secure/jas/create" style="height: 443px;">
                            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                            <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
                                <head>
                                    <body class="browserFF browserFF3 Init">
                                        <div class="xicSeamlessUI" xic:app="Create" xic:title="Create">
                                            <span id="bFeedback" class="feedback"> </span>
                                            <div id="confirmationWindow69" xic:width="50%">
                                                <div id="contentModalWindow6c" xic:width="50%">
                                                    <input id="hiddenText" class="xicInputText" type="text" size="1" style="visibility:hidden" name="hiddenText">
                                                        <input id="hiddenCheckBox" type="checkbox" onclick="var wcall=wicketAjaxPost('?wicket:interface=:0:hiddenCheckBox::IBehaviorListener:0:', wicketSerialize(Wicket.$('hiddenCheckBox')),null,null, function() {return Wicket.$('hiddenCheckBox') != null;}.bind(this));" name="hiddenCheckBox" style="visibility: hidden">
                                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td width="83%"> </td>
                                                                        <td width="17%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                                                                            <label id="categoryDescription65">Select Category: </label>
                                                                            <span id="categoryDescriptionDropDown66">
                                                                                <div class="xicInputWrapper xicInputWrapperSelect">
                                                                                    <select id="cellDropDown67" class="xicSmartSelectLoaded" name="categoryDescriptionDropDown:cellDropDown" onchange=".page.showPleaseWait('Processing...');var wcall=wicketAjaxPost('?wicket:interface=:0:categoryDescriptionDropDown:cellDropDown::IBehaviorListener:0:', wicketSerialize(Wicket.$('cellDropDown67')),null,null, function() {return Wicket.$('cellDropDown67') != null;}.bind(this));">
                                                                                        <option value="0" selected="selected">New</option>
                                                                                        <option value="1">Basic</option>
                                                                                        <option value="2">Advanced</option>
                                                                                        <option value="3">Premium</option>
                                                                                        <option value="4">Other</option>
                                                                                    </select>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                            <div id="myPleaseWait22" class="xicPleaseWait xicFullPageZIndex" style="z-index: 2000; display: none;">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div id="PleaseWait" class="xicPleaseWait xicFullPageZIndex" style="z-index: 6000; display: none;">
                                    </body>
                            </html>
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, there are two frames 1 is active and other hidden.

### Exception:

```
timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:css=>"select[name*='Description']", :tag_name=>"select"} to become present (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
```

This seems to me an IEDriver issue when i tried with firefox and chrome it is working fine

Comment: What does stacktrace tell you? Can't it find iframe or element inside iframe?

Comment: Where did you get the html you shared? I do not see a select list in it, which might be why Watir is timing out looking for it.

Comment: Justin, HTML is huge so, I removed most of it now i have added..it

Comment: I have the same issue how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly switching to the frame in question worked for me.

First you switch to the frame and once you are done working inside the frame don't forget to return to your default content:

```
driver.switch_to.frame "frameName"

Do your stuff within IFrame

driver.switch_to.default_content
```

To find the solution [the selenium docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) were helpful as well as a [this](http://www.assertselenium.com/webdriver/handling-iframes-using-webdriver/) post about handling Iframes with selenium webdriver.